# Flask-WTF StopValidation after default validator fails

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-wtforms

I am adding a field and validating it against `IPAddress` WTForms' validator:

```py
from ipaddress import ip_network

from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, IPAddress, ValidationError, StopValidation

class CreateForm(FlaskForm):
    ip = StringField(
        label="IP Address",
        validators=[DataRequired(), IPAddress(ipv4=True)],
        render_kw={"autocomplete": False, "placeholder": "IP Address"},
    )
...
```

However, some extra custom validations are required and are defined as:

```py
...
def validate_ip(self, ip):
        if not ip_network(ip.data).overlaps(ip_network('192.168.1.1/24')):
            raise ValidationError(f"{ip.data} is out of bound for 192.168.1.1!")
...
```

When I add an IP address for example `192.168.1.256` which is obviously an invalid IP, The validation is not stopped because `StopValidation` is not called and I get the exception raised in the browser, not under the field I want.

A workaround to this is to create a custom validator, the same as the built-in validator, before any other validations and raise the `StopValidation`:

```py
...
def validate_ip(self, ip):
         try:
            ip_address(ip.data)
        except Exception as e:
            raise StopValidation(e) from e
        if not ip_network(ip.data).overlaps(ip_network('192.168.1.1/24')):
            raise ValidationError(f"{ip.data} is out of bound for 192.168.1.1!")
...
```

The question is how can I stop validation on the first validation error which is the default built-in validator in this case? If the default validation is invalid, stop the validation chain immediately, else continue with the rest of the validation rules.

> I feel that recreating the built-in validator as a custom validator is a bit DRY.